# Long pause after typing `std::` when using semantic with auto-complete

Tags: auto-complete-mode, semantic-mode

I am using `auto-complete-mode` with `ac-c-headers` and whenever I type `std::` There is a long (~30 seconds) pause, presumably while the candidates list is populated.  This happens every time, which suggests that there is no caching to speed things up for the next time.

Is there a way to avoid the pause after every time I type `std::`?

### Update

Using the emacs profiler, I have now discovered that the pretty much all of the time is being spent in the functions `semantic-analyze-possible-completions` and `semantic-analyze-current-context`. This suggests that the real problem probably lies with semantic.  I have also learned that including anything from the Boost libraries causes a significant increase in the amount of time required for semantic to return possible completions.

(In case it makes a difference, I am using Emacs 24.5 on Linux)

Comment: I don't use `auto-complete-mode`, but **30 seconds is really long!** If you don't get an answer here, consider contacting the package maintainer -- 30 sec is long enough to suspect a bug. You might also try debugging it, with `M-x debug-on-entry` for the function that performs the completion.

Comment: You're not on Windows or Cygwin are you?

Comment: @nanny: no, this is on RHEL.

Comment: Are you satisfied with disabling semantic-mode and only leave auto-complete-mode on?

Comment: Same problem here. Have you solved the issue in the meanwhile ?

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this same problem before and I "solved" it by changing the value of `ac-delay` from 0.1s to 1.0, like so:

```el
(set-variable 'ac-delay 1.0)
```

That means that as I'm typing it only attempts the auto-complete if I stop typing for a second.  So if you know you want a `std::vector` you can just keep typing and `auto-complete` never fires.